# Django I'm trying to write a test for my add_post view and it's not working

Tags: django, testing

my view:

```
def add_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your post was added successfully.")
            return redirect("food-feed")

        messages.info(
            request,
            "If you're adding a recipe you must include the ingredients, instructions and cooking time.",
        )

    form = NewPostForm()
    return render(request, "post/add_post.html", {"addpost_form": form})
```

forms.py

```
class NewPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "post_description",
            "main_image",
            "is_recipe",
            "ingredients",
            "recipe_description",
            "cooking_time",
        ]
```

test

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile 


class TestPost(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser(username='creatingsometest', password='passwordfortesting')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.user.delete()
    
    def test_add_post(self):
        self.client.login(username='creatingsometest', password='passwordfortesting')
        response = self.client.post(
            "/add-post/",
            {
                'title': 'TESTCASE TITLE', 
                'post_description': 'TESTCASE POSTDESCRIPTION', 
                'main_image': SimpleUploadedFile(name='test_image.jpg', content=''),
                'is_recipe': 'on',
                'ingredients': '',
                'recipe_description':'',
                'cooking_time': '',
                '_save': 'Save',
            },
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, "/food-feed")
```

The test if failing

> self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302) AssertionError: 200 != 302

Also I don't really know how to handle the ImageField (main_image) and the BooleanField(is_recipe). Regarding to the ImageField I read about "SimpleUploadedFile" but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly.
When I printed response.content above the self.assertEqual I see the html that corresponds to the add-post form.

Comment: You can check the `response.context['form'].errors` to see which field caused the error. Can you update your answer with that, please?

Comment: Where should I add it? Because I write that line above the self.assertEqual and I get this: 
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'form'

Comment: Sorry, 'addpost_form' instead of 'form'

Comment: @vinkomlacic I'm not getting any other messages than the first one, self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302) AssertionError: 200 != 302